# how to read files from a folder that were created before a date

Tags: sas, pipe, filenames

I am trying to use SAS to read multiple files from a directory and they were created before a date.

I have used this code to help me to read all the files. It works perfectly. Now I found out that only some files that were created before a certain date are what I need. I think that could be done either by FILENAME PIPE Dir options or by INFILE statement options, but I cannot find the answers.

code source:

http://support.sas.com/kb/41/880.html

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "C:\_today\file*.csv" /b ';

data dirlist ;
   infile dirlist lrecl=200 truncover;
   input file_name $100.;
run;

data _null_;
   set dirlist end=end;
   count+1;
   call symputx('read'||put(count,4.-l),cats('c:\_today\',file_name));
   call symputx('dset'||put(count,4.-l),scan(file_name,1,'.'));
   if end then call symputx('max',count);
run;

options mprint symbolgen;
%macro readin;
   %do i=1 %to &max;

      data &&dset&i;
         infile "&&read&i" lrecl=1000 truncover dsd;
         input var1 $ var2 $ var3 $;
       run;

   %end;
%mend readin;

%readin;
```

Comment: How do you know the 'created date'? Is it part of the file name, or file properties?

Comment: The created date is sort of part of the file name. Each file name is like this: file as of 06-17-19. But seems this kind of format is not good enough as a date format. So what I was planning is to use the file property. Thank you!

Comment: No, you can easily parse a date like that in SAS, not sure why you're saying you can't. Post what you've tried. If you move the files you have the potential of the dates changing so you should consider using the date in the file name.

Comment: Hi Reeza, I use a substr function to get that month number and add it back to dirlist dataset. Now I can do where clause to filter out the dates I don't need. Thank you so much! It is much easier than what I thought.

Comment: SCAN() is another good function that will let you parse components from strings. Glad it helped.

Comment: Thank you Reeza!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are reading in just the file names using the `dir` command.  The existing `/b` modifier is saying print just the file name and nothing else.  You want to change it to read both the file name and the CREATED date of the file.  In order to do that it gets a little messy.  You will need to change that pipe command from:

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "C:\_today\file*.csv" /b ';
```

...to this... :

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "C:\_today\file*.csv" /tc ';
```

The output will change from something like this:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
...
```

...to something like this... :

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 90ED-A122

 Directory of C:\_today

01/13/2017  09:14 AM             1,991 file1.csv
01/11/2017  11:43 AM               169 file2.csv
...
...
...
01/11/2017  11:43 AM               169 file99.csv

          99 File(s)          6,449 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  57,999,806,464 bytes free
```

So you will then need to modify your data step that creates `dirlist` to clean up the results returned by the new `dir` statement.  You will need to ignore the header and footer and read in the date and time etc.  Once you have that date and time in the appropriate SAS format, you can then just use a SAS `where` clause to keep the rows you are interested in.  I will leave this as an exercise for you to do.  If you have trouble with it you can always open a new question.

If you need more information on the `dir` command, you can open up a command prompt (Start Menu->Run->"cmd"), and then type in `dir /?` to see a list of available switches for the `dir` command.  You may find a slightly different combination of switches for it that better suits your task than what I listed above.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! Appreciated! Very detail and clear. I will try it tomorrow!

Comment: Hi Robert, I have tried /tc, like what you have described, it has headings. But I got their property information, like date and time. Since I need to have another field to add seq with each file, the headers are named by seq too. So I choose Reeza's suggestion. But I will try this one later to practice how to clean up headers. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, thank you for letting me know how to find dir /? options. Since I cannot find any documentations online about SAS Pipe Dir options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `powershell` to leverage the features of the operating system.

```
filename get_them pipe 
" powershell -command 
  ""
    dir c:\temp 
    | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt '3/19/2019'}
    | select -property name
    | ft -hidetableheader
  ""
";

data _null_;
  infile get_them;
  input;
  putlog _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Hello Richard, this method looks cool! I haven't tried it yet. But I will look into it. Thank you so much!